# Remove combining accents from string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My attempt:

```sql
select replace (N'ко́шка', NCHAR(0x0301), N'')
```

The result I want is `кошка`, i.e. the same string with the COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT removed.

Is there a way to achieve this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a binary collation override:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'ко́шка' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, NCHAR(0x0301), '')
```

Non-binary collations essentially ignore combining characters for purposes of comparisons (including those needed for `REPLACE`), since they're semantically part of the character they combine with.