# Regex not matching ACUTE ACCENT

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove combining accents (\u0301) placed over illegal characters such as a whitespace:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "✧ ́зу́б";
        string r1 = text.Replace(" \u0301", " ");
        string r2 = Regex.Replace(text, " \u0301́", " ", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        Console.WriteLine(r1); // ✧ зу́б
        Console.WriteLine(r2); // ✧ ́зу́б
        Console.WriteLine(r1 == r2); // False
    }
}
```

The simple `text.Replace()` works as expected. Why doesn't the Regex work?

I've had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67538550/1291717) in T-SQL and it was resolved by specifying a binary collation. I thought `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant` might do the trick but it didn't.

Comment: looks like your `\u0301` in the regex has an acute accent on `1`

Comment: @PhuNgo You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At minimum remove the acute accent `" \u0301́"` from the regex replace. Secondly not all " " spaces are the same. To avoid any possible situations with tabs vs spaces, I would recommend that you remove the space and work with general spaces of the `\s`.

So, change the `" \u0301́"` to `"\s+\u0301"` to avoid two possible failure points.